# matplotlib - Large Heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried search on the site for a solution, but haven't found one that is working for me.
I'm trying to plot a pretty large heatmap - x-axis has 21 containers and y-axis has 18.  I'm reading the data in from a CSV, and for the most part, the cells are empty - except for a few.  I'm also trying to label the axes.

When I plot the heatmap, it doesn't show the entire thing.  I'm not sure if its a problem with the formatting of the figure, or the heatmap.  If I leave any formatting out, the plot works - but it doesn't show all the rows/column.  When I try to change the axes limits, or set the size of the figure, it essentially breaks the plot and the values don't show up accurately.

How do I make it show all columns and rows, even if the values cells are empty?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x_labels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'
     'G','H','I','J','K','L',
     'M','N','O','P','Q','R',
     'S','T','U']
y_labels =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J',
     'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R']

#reading in a CSV, data in the file is mostly empty - only 3 of the cells have values in them.  I included a link to what the .csv looks like
metrics = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", index_col=0)

fig, ir = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ir.pcolor(metrics, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)

#trying to set the axis labels.  Should this reference the column and row labels in the csv instead of the variable I created?
ir.set_xticklabels(x_labels, minor=False)
ir.set_yticklabels(y_labels, minor=False)

ir.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

Here's a screenshot of what the `csv` file looks like:
[image: csv file]

This is the plot I get
[image: current_heatmap]

This is a screenshot of a print of the dataframe
[image: datafame_output]

Comment: Have you checked if all the data is transfered to the variable `metrics` correctly?. Maybe you reduce your example by removing the `.csv` import and generate dummy data to test in python itselve.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709050/draw-csv-file-data-as-a-heatmap-using-numpy-and-matplotlib) is an example that might be helpful. First check that the data is loaded correctly, then make sure that it is plotted correctly.

Comment: I did a simple print(metrics) and the output showed that the entire csv was read in correctly.

Comment: I think the problem might actually be with the formatting of the axis labels.  I either have to make the font smaller, or rotate the words to display vertically.  Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: could you upload an image of your current plot, so we can see what the problem looks like?

Comment: @tom - I added a screenshot of what the current plot looks like (current_heatmap) and another of what the print(metrics) shows for the contents of the dataframe (dataframe_output)

Comment: seaborn has a neat heatmap plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happened is that you're setting the labels for the ticks, but not changing their location.

If you'd like ticklabels at every cell, they'll you'll need specify that you'd like ticks there as well.

For example, you could do something like:

```
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(len(xlabels)), xticklabels=xlabels,
       yticks=np.arange(len(ylabels)), yticklabels=ylabels)
```

You'll also likely want to limit your x/y ranges to the limit of the data.

Additionally, you might using `imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')` or `matshow(data)` instead of `pcolor`.  First, they're much faster.  Second, the default extents will *center* each cell over integer values instead of placing the *edge* of the cell at the integer value.  Additionally, `matshow`/`imshow` will limit the range of the axes to the range of the data.

For example, using `pcolor` we'd get:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'ABCDEFGHIKJLMNOPQRSTUV'
data = np.random.random((len(labels), len(labels)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(data)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(len(labels)), xticklabels=labels,
       yticks=np.arange(len(labels)), yticklabels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

While with `matshow`, we could do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'ABCDEFGHIKJLMNOPQRSTUV'
data = np.random.random((len(labels), len(labels)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.matshow(data)
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(len(labels)), xticklabels=labels,
       yticks=np.arange(len(labels)), yticklabels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thinks that matshow is prefered over pcolor. But your problems is the ticks positions, so you need to change them too, not only the labels:

```
ir.matshow(metrics, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)

ir.set_xticks(range(len(x_labels)))
ir.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
ir.set_yticks(range(len(y_labels)))
ir.set_yticklabels(y_labels)
```

In your case, the x/yticks positions that are automatically generated are:

```
array([  0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.,  25.])
```

And the label you pass will go to these positions for the 6 first labels because you only have 6 defined ticks positions. This what you see, A,B,C,D,E and F on the x axis. So you could fix that quickly with:

```
ir.set_xticklabels(x_labels[::5])
```

instead of

```
ir.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
```

And you'll get `AFJPU` as labels at the correct position. But if you want all labels, you need to create the position of the ticks

Remains the problem of `x/ylim` which are automatically set when using `matshow`. The other advantage of `matshow`, is that is centers the labels in the columns or row (as shown in Joe Kington's answer). But in that case too, you'll need to define your ticks positions, because with `matshow`, the `xticks` are even weirder (not sure why they do it like his, maybe it belongs to setting the aspect ration properly), anyway you have something like this:

```
xticks: [-5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0]
labels: [u'', u'0', u'5', u'10', u'15', u'20', u'']
```

So here if you don't redefine the `xticks`, you'll have your first label outside of the plot (at position -5).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

@JoeKington's answer is correct - you need to set the tick locations before you set the tick labels.

An alternative way to do that is to use the [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module, and use a [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator), set to a multiple of `1` - i.e. one tick every cell.

For your example, it would look something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x_labels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'
     'G','H','I','J','K','L',
     'M','N','O','P','Q','R',
     'S','T','U']
y_labels =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J',
     'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R']

#reading in a CSV, data in the file is mostly empty - only 3 of the cells have values in them.  I included a link to what the .csv looks like
metrics = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", index_col=0)

fig, ir = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ir.pcolor(metrics, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)

ir.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ir.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

ir.set_xticklabels(x_labels, minor=False)
ir.set_yticklabels(y_labels, minor=False)

ir.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks - setting the tick locations got it working!  Thanks all.